# string manipulation in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, string

I have a string of the format,

```
/d.phpsoft_id=369242&url=http://f.1mobile.com/mobile_software/finance/com.mshift.android.achieva_2.apk
```

and i need to edit this string using regular expression that the result string should start from http: ie the resultatnt string should be

```
http://f.1mobile.com/mobile_software/finance/com.mshift.android.achieva_2.apk
```

please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
str = "/d.phpsoft_id=369242&url=http://f.1mobile.com/mobile_software/finance/com.mshift.android.achieva_2.apk"

str.spl­it("url=")­[1]
```

Comment: This will break if there is another `url=` anywhere else.

Comment: You're going to pass multiple url parameters? Define the requirements please.

Answer (score 1):

For these types of situations, I prefer to go with readily available tools that will help provide a solution or at the very least will point me in the right direction. My favourite for regex is [txt2re](http://txt2re.com/) because it will output example code in many languages, including ruby.

After running your string through the parser and selecting httpurl for matching, it [output](http://txt2re.com/index-ruby.php3?s=/d.phpsoft_id=369242&url=http://f.1mobile.com/mobile_software/finance/com.mshift.android.achieva_2.apk&1):

```
txt='/d.phpsoft_id=369242&url=http://f.1mobile.com/mobile_software/finance/com.mshift.android.achieva_2.apk'

re1='.*?'   # Non-greedy match on filler
re2='((?:http|https)(?::\\/{2}[\\w]+)(?:[\\/|\\.]?)(?:[^\\s"]*))'   # HTTP URL 1

re=(re1+re2)
m=Regexp.new(re,Regexp::IGNORECASE);
if m.match(txt)
    httpurl1=m.match(txt)[1];
    puts "("<<httpurl1<<")"<< "\n"
end
```

Comment: What if there are multiple url's in the params? How do you know you want the first match?

Answer (score 0):

**Simple Answer**

You need to do following

```
str = "/d.phpsoft_id=369242&url=http://f.1mobile.com/mobile_software/finance/com.mshift.android.achieva_2.apk"

start=str.index('http://')

resultant=str[start,str.length]
```